# How to clear method call parameters/arguments filled by SublimeText Jedi-autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I am testing out SublimeText auto-complete using JEDI package and one problem I am having is unrequired parameters are auto-filling function/method calls:

For example in Flask:
I can just call the function as such:

```
app.run(),
```

but JEDI-Autocomplete is doing something like this:

```
app.run(host=     , port=..., debug=..., load_dotenv=...)
```

I can't figure out how to clear the parameters as it's not needed in this case.

Same problem with:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Instead  autocomplete is automatically filling in unrequired parameters and seemingly forcing me to add value to each argument.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the Sublime Text 3's SublimeJEDI repo ([issue #290 - open() autocompletes all args when in required mode](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI/issues/290)) seems to suggests that there's an option to control autocomplete aggressiveness:

```
"auto_complete_function_params": "all",
```

In your preference settings (either user preferences or syntax preferences).

From their [README.md](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI/blob/ae823a97155a2328d2d05af1b183a99351a43589/README.md):

> Function parameters completion has 3 different behaviors:
>
> Insert all function arguments on autocomplete:
>
> ```
> # complete result
> func(a, b, c, d=True, e=1, f=None)
>
> # sublime_jedi.sublime-settings
> {
>     "auto_complete_function_params": "all"
> }
> ```
>
> Insert only required arguments that don't have default value (default behavior):
>
> ```
> # complete result
> func(a, b, c)
>
> # sublime_jedi.sublime-settings
> {
>     "auto_complete_function_params": "required"
> }
>
> Do not insert any arguments:
>
> # complete result
> func()
>
> # sublime_jedi.sublime-settings
> {
>     "auto_complete_function_params": ""
> }
> ```
>
> [More info about auto_complete_function_params](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI/wiki/What-is-%22auto_complete_function_params%22)

You may experiment with those options to see what fits you better.

Turning auto_complete off and using `SublimeJedi: ShowDocstring` (defaults to `Ctrl+Alt+D`) when the cursor is *after* the function name fixes the issue for me.

You can also hover over the function name or use `SublimeJedi: Show Signature`.